# Reduce font size of particular line in algorithm and algorithmic pseudocode

Tags: fonts, algorithms, algorithmic, pseudocode

I want to reduce the font size of a particular line in an algorithm pseudocode where I use `algorithm` and `algorithmic` package. How can I do it? For example in the following I want to fit line 9 in one line:

```
\STATE $w_h^{k,j} = w_h^{k,j-1} - \eta_k \nabla L_k^h(w_h^{k,j-1}) + \sqrt{2\eta_k \beta_k^{-1}}\epsilon_h^{k,j}$
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Algorithm}
\date{January 2023}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\twocolumn
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{\label{Algorithm:LMC} LMC}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE Input: step sizes $\{\eta_k > 0\}_{k\geq 1}$, inverse temperature $\{\beta_k\}_{k\geq 1}$, loss function $L_k(w)$. 
\STATE Initialize $w_h^{1,0} =  \textbf{0}$ for $h \in [H]$, $J_0 = 0$.
\FOR{episode $k=1,2,\ldots, K$}
\STATE Receive the initial state $s_1^k$.

\FOR{step $h=H, H-1,\ldots, 1$}
    \STATE $w_h^{k,0} = w_h^{k-1, J_{k-1}}$\label{line:warm-start}
    \FOR{$j = 1, \ldots, J_k$}
        \STATE $\epsilon_h^{k,j} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$
        \STATE $w_h^{k,j} = w_h^{k,j-1} - \eta_k \nabla L_k^h(w_h^{k,j-1}) + \sqrt{2\eta_k \beta_k^{-1}}\epsilon_h^{k,j}$
    \ENDFOR

\STATE  $Q^k_{h}(\cdot,\cdot) \leftarrow Q(w_h^{k,J_k};\phi(\cdot, \cdot))$  \label{algline:q-update}
\STATE  $V^k_{h}(\cdot) \leftarrow \max_{a \in \mathcal{A}} Q_{h}^{k}(\cdot,a)$.
~\label{Alg:min-for-Q}
\ENDFOR


\FOR{step $h=1, 2, \ldots, H$}

\STATE Take  action  $a^k_{h} \leftarrow \argmax_{a \in \mathcal{A}} Q_h^{k}(s_h^k,a)$.
\STATE  Observe reward $r^k_{h}(s_h^k,a_h^k)$, get next state $s^k_{h+1}$. 
\ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're not at all concerned about what the output will look like by (say) scaling things down to fit? Of course, you're making it easy on yourself by using `twocolumn` mode either. I'd recommend adding some `\STATE`s where you define some more terms (like `\STATE $\Delta = \eta_k \nabla L_k^h(w_h^{k,j-1}) + \sqrt{2\eta_k \beta_k^{-1}}\epsilon_h^{k,j}$` and then use something like `\STATE $w_h^{k,j} = w_h^{k,j-1} + \Delta$`. This tackles line 9... what about line 16?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reducing the font size, I'd split the formula across lines.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\DeclareMathOperator{\argmax}{arg\,max}


\begin{document}

\title{Algorithm}
\author{hi15}
\date{January 2023}

\maketitle

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{\label{Algorithm:LMC} LMC}
\raggedright
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE Input: step sizes $\{\eta_k > 0\}_{k\geq 1}$,
       inverse temperature $\{\beta_k\}_{k\geq 1}$, loss function $L_k(w)$. 
\STATE Initialize $w_h^{1,0} =  \mathbf{0}$ for $h \in [H]$, $J_0 = 0$.
\FOR{episode $k=1,2,\dots, K$}
  \STATE Receive the initial state $s_1^k$.

  \FOR{step $h=H, H-1,\dots, 1$}
    \STATE $w_h^{k,0} = w_h^{k-1, J_{k-1}}$\label{line:warm-start}
    \FOR{$j = 1, \dots, J_k$}
      \STATE $\epsilon_h^{k,j} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$
      \STATE $\begin{aligned}[t]
                 w_h^{k,j} = w_h^{k,j-1}
                 & - \eta_k \nabla L_k^h(w_h^{k,j-1})
                 \\
                 & + \sqrt{\smash[b]{2\eta_k^{\vphantom{-1}} \beta_k^{-1}}}\,\epsilon_h^{k,j}
             \end{aligned}$
    \ENDFOR

    \STATE  $Q^k_{h}(\cdot,\cdot) \leftarrow Q(w_h^{k,J_k};\phi(\cdot, \cdot))$
            \label{algline:q-update}
    \STATE  $V^k_{h}(\cdot) \leftarrow \max_{a \in \mathcal{A}} Q_{h}^{k}(\cdot,a)$.
            \label{Alg:min-for-Q}
  \ENDFOR

  \FOR{step $h=1, 2, \dots, H$}
    \STATE Take  action  $a^k_{h} \leftarrow \argmax_{a \in \mathcal{A}} Q_h^{k}(s_h^k,a)$.
    \STATE  Observe reward $r^k_{h}(s_h^k,a_h^k)$, get next state $s^k_{h+1}$. 
  \ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I added `\,` after the square root so it's easier for the reader to parse the formula. The `^{\vphantom{-1}}` trick moves the subscript to the same level as the next symbol; `\smash[b]` reduces the size of the square root and there's no need to compensate for the missing depth because the square roots is above blank space.

I changed `\textbf` to the correct `\mathbf` and `\ldots` to `\dots`.

Finally, `\raggedright` avoids clumsy hyphenation and underfull boxes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\resizebox` in `graphicx` such as:

```latex
\STATE \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\ $w_h^{k,j} = w_h^{k,j-1} - \eta_k \nabla L_k^h(w_h^{k,j-1}) + \sqrt{2\eta_k \beta_k^{-1}}\epsilon_h^{k,j}$}
```

[image]